# Nested for loops not functioning

Tags: for-loop, python-3.x, pygame

I have this code:

```
def makeBoard():
    squareX = 0
    squareY = 0
    squareType = "dark"
    darkSquare = imageLoader("darkBrownSquare.png")
    lightSquare = imageLoader("lightBrownSquare.png")
    for x in range(8):
        for y in range(8):
            if squareType == "dark":
                MAIN_SURF.blit(darkSquare, (squareX, squareY))
                squareType = "light"
            elif squareType == "light":
                MAIN_SURF.blit(lightSquare, (squareX, squareY))
                squareType = "dark"
            squareY += 64
        squareX += 64
```

It's meant to draw a checkerboard pattern, but I only get this instead:
[image]
I assume it's because of the for loops, and the fact that they are nested, but otherwise, I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

You need to zero squareY after finish its loop.

So after

```
squareX +=64
```

Just add

```
squareY = 0
```

Moreover, you can write a more readable code if you use range function step parameter and use the x and y instead of squareX and squareY (this will handle this bug as well)

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `squareX` and `squareY` stuff and just create the right values of `x` and `y` from the beginning:

```
for x in range(0, 64, 8):
    for y in range(0, 64, 8):
```

Or multiply them by `8`:

```
MAIN_SURF.blit(darkSquare, (8 * x, 8 * y))
```